# Javascript - Looping and adding a class to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm at work and have to change a small bit of Jquery code so that it only uses Javascript, no Jquery. I haven't been taught how to use only Javascript, I've only been taught how to use Jquery with Javascript (I know, that's horrible). This is the Jquery code:

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.Content ul li a').click( function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
            counter += 1;
        }

        if (counter == 3) {
            // call a function
        }
   });

});
```

The code is fairly small. Can someone convert that to just Javascript for me?

Comment: It'll cost `$20`  !

Comment: _jQuery_ is "Javascript"!!!

Comment: @MohammadAdil lol c'mon, it's only one small bit of code, and it's the only code I have to change. I don't want to learn Jquery to Javascript  conversion (which is just learning proper Javascript) for just this small bit of code.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I know Jquery, I don't know Javascript (which is probably pretty clear now after reading my question)

Comment: And where are you stuck? Any attempt on your side?

Comment: Everything is not _taught_.

Comment: You cannot know jQuery without knowing javascript, that doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Break the code down into parts and start investigating what each part does and how to replicate it. That way you'll learn something too.

Comment: Start make a small function & try this
And fired on onclick

Comment: Here's a useful page to begin with: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/init.php. It deals with DOM ready and attaching event listeners.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks for a workforce, not help.

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't have an attempt, I didn't want to spend time learning how to select elements, add classes and check if they had classes etc. using just JS without Jquery at the moment, I might learn it over the weekend but right now I just needed to get it done.

Comment: @A.Wolff in an interview, if my question was 'do you know Javascript?' and if the person said yes and if I made him write code which does what the I want the code in the question to do, and if he does it with Jquery and if I asked the person to do it without Jquery and he says he doesn't know how to, I wouldn't consider him as someone who knows JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/29Sby/1/**

```
<style>
.clicked{color:green; font-weight:bold;}
</style>

<a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0); /*put URLs here if you need to*/" onclick="doStuff(this)">LINK 1</a><br/>
<a id="link2" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doStuff(this)">LINK 2</a><br/>
<a id="link3" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doStuff(this)">LINK 3</a><br/>
<a id="link4" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doStuff(this)">LINK 4</a><br/>
<a id="link5" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doStuff(this)">LINK 5</a><br/>

<script>
var counter = 0;

doStuff=function(obj)
{
    //alert(obj.id);
    if (obj.className === 'clicked') {
        //do nothing
        alert('already clicked');
    } else {
        obj.className = 'clicked';
        counter += 1;
    }

    if (counter === 3) {
        alert('call a function if you want');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hasClass() equivalent would be to check for className indexOf of string class, an element could have more than one class